# Preparing a mac application for upload to the App Store

Tags: cocoa, macos, app-store

I want to upload a mac application to the App Store.

What do I need to prepare about icons, sourcecode?

For example, for an iPhone app I need two icons (57x57 for iphone, 512x512 for iTunes - iTunesArtwork), what about for mac applications?

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to prepare icons is using the Icon Composer application included with the Developer Tools. (/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Icon Composer)

It will create a special autoresizing .icns image. When you export your icon from Photoshop or whatever save it as a 512x512 image. Paste it into Icon Composer and export it as an .icns. Set the exported image as the icon file in the app's plist.

You can refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TPXREF120) for some more specifics. (scroll down to "Creating Icons")

Comment: thank you so much. When I read [A Suggested Process for Creating Icons]() part, I'm confused icon size. What size (512x512,128x128,32x32,16x16) should I choose the best?

Comment: best: all of them. At least: 128x128.